# Loop function for missing data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random, list-comprehension

I want to change NaN values with `np.random.normal(mu,s,n)` function with the list comprehension method, but I couldn't.

```
df_column_values = ["NaN","1","NaN","2","NaN","3","94","4","168","5","NaN"]

n, mu, sigma = 700, 155, 118
array = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)
for i in array:
    if i > 0 and i < 400:    
        data['Insulin'].replace(0,(i), inplace=True)
```

This function works, but the output is same for all NaN values.
How can I improve this code?

Raw data from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database)

Comment: Could you please also share a sample of your dataframe with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace missing values with normally distributed random values within a range (0, 400). You need to use truncated normal distribution for this.

Then you should create a vector of random variables of the same length as the data you are potentially replacing.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame({'Insulin': ["NaN","1","NaN","2","NaN","3",
"94","4","168","5","NaN"]})
​
import scipy.stats as stats
​
lower, upper = 0, 400
mu, sigma = 155, 118
X = stats.truncnorm(
    (lower - mu) / sigma, 
    (upper - mu) / sigma, 
    loc=mu, scale=sigma)
​
data['Insulin'] = np.where(
     data['Insulin']=="NaN", 
     X.rvs(len(data)),
     data['Insulin'])

data['Insulin'] = np.where(
     data['Insulin'].isna(), 
     X.rvs(len(data)),
     data['Insulin'])

print(data)
```

```
       Insulin
0    59.069239
1            1
2   113.143013
3            2
4    63.488282
5            3
6           94
7            4
8          168
9            5
10  109.272469
```

Comment: I can run but I cant take values.

Comment: My NaN values doesnt change thank you

`df=pd.read_csv('../input/diabetes.csv')
datainsulin = df
datainsulin['Insulin'].replace(0,(np.NaN), inplace=True)

lower, upper = 0, 400
mu, sigma = 155, 118
X = stats.truncnorm(
    (lower - mu) / sigma, 
    (upper - mu) / sigma, 
    loc=mu, scale=sigma)

datainsulin['Insulin'] = np.where(
     datainsulin['Insulin']=="NaN", 
     X.rvs(len(datainsulin)),
     datainsulin['Insulin'])

print(datainsulin.head())`

[data_cvs](https://www.kaggle.com/ravichaubey1506/multivariate-statistical-analysis-on-diabetes/data?select=diabetes.csv)

Comment: Since you have not shared your data, I do not know in what format your NaN values are read. Also you should not replace your NaN values with 0, if you want to replace them with Random values later. You can change the condition to isna() if you are actually reading in the NaN values as NaN and not as text as in the example you pasted above.

data['Insulin'] = np.where(
     data['Insulin'].isna(), 
     X.rvs(len(data)),
     data['Insulin'])

Comment: Great, thank you my problem is solved. Thank you Giedrius